# Update not working in SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a piece of code which updates a row in my table when clicked on List Item. 
  Here is the code,

```
    list_replace.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Parent,View v, int Position, long id) {

            ContentValues cvs = new ContentValues();

           cvs.put(COLUMN_NAME_READING_MODE, ReadingMode);
           cvs.put(COLUMN_NAME_PASTDATETIME, StartDate);
           cvs.put("EndDateTime", CurrentDateTime);
           cvs.put(COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE,Reading);
           DB.update(TABLE_NAME, cvs, "_Id =" + id, null);

          DB.close();

        }
    });
```

But I don't see any record updated in my table. Please correct me.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Before doing updation open your database `DB.open()`  i think you missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_replace.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Parent,View v, int Position, long id) {

        ContentValues cvs = new ContentValues();

       cvs.put(COLUMN_NAME_READING_MODE, ReadingMode);
       cvs.put(COLUMN_NAME_PASTDATETIME, StartDate);
       cvs.put("EndDateTime", CurrentDateTime);
       cvs.put(COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE,Reading);
       SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);   // add this line
       db.update(TABLE_NAME, cvs, "_Id =" + id, null);

       db.close();

    }
});
```

Comment: Ah!! That's the mistake I did. Good catch!! Thanks.